# Increase php font size

Tags: php, image, browser, font-size, imagettftext

I am trying to create an image by using PHP. This image is supposed to have text on it. I am only able to get the text displayed by using **imagestring** function, but this function only allows font size of upto 5. As it turns out, this is too small or tiny of a font for me. Then, I learned you can have text as big as you want on your image by using **imagettftext** function. This function doesn't work for me at all. I found this code in another stackoverflow question while I was researching on this issue.

```
<?php
$image = imagecreate(400,300);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,255);

if(!isset($_GET['size'])) $_GET['size'] = 44;
if(!isset($_GET['text'])) $_GET['text'] = "Hello, world!";

// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'arial.ttf';

imagettftext($image, $_GET['size'], 15, 50, 200, $white, $font, $_GET['text']);
header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

I see funny faces and weird characters on the browser when I call it up. What is wrong this code and what other options available for increasing font size in PHP?

**UPDATE**
After much research on this, I've tried all the suggestions and answers that were given online for this issue, but still it won't display image. I added **./** in front of the font type string. I even uploaded a Microsoft font type from my computer to the server and still ended up with the same result.

**UPDATE**
I did forget to mention that I actually did transfer font type arial.ttf from my computer to the server into the folder where all of my php files resides.

Comment: Isn't Arial spelled "Arial"?

Comment: @dmikester1 i just corrected the spelling and still the same.

Comment: the instructions say to skip the extension on the font, not sure if that matters

Comment: although, looking through the examples, it appears that everyone is using the extension.  Someone did mention this, stick a ./ in front like so: "$myfont = "./coolfont.ttf";

Comment: @dmikester1 made the change still no change.

Comment: is it actually producing an image with the funny characters?  or are the funny characters you are seeing code on the page?

Comment: @dmikester1 I am seeing this `‰PNG  IHDR,×ywPLTEÿÿÿÿ{Ü™,&IDAThíÁ1Â õOm O €§;ÄþWr IEND®B`‚ `

Comment: so I take it to mean that is straight up text and not an actual image?

Comment: @dmikester1, is it possible that my server doesn't have the required font types - free font types. I am actually using a third-party server not of my own to test this code.

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: it's possible the font is missing on your server, can you test locally?  I don't have a lot of experience with displaying a png in a browser, but you might not be sending it to the browser correctly.

Comment: It looks like your browser does not know what to do with the data and is spitting out the text code representing the image. (I'm just guessing on this)

Comment: @dmikester1 I even used JQuery on a HTML page and pulled this PHP code and displayed it as an Image. Still nothing. All I see is broken image icon.

Comment: If you are seeing `‰PNG IHDR,×ywPLTEÿÿÿÿ{Ü™,&IDAThíÁ1Â õOm O €§;ÄþWr IEND®B‚`, this is a PNG header and the start of some data. In other words. I think you are getting an actual PNG image, but you are looking at the image data instead of the image itself. It's hard to guess what is going on, so I would start by enabling error reporting and checking the result values of functions like `imagettftext` (which returns `false` in case of an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> fontfile The path to the TrueType font you wish to use.
>
> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.

Remove the .ttf or add an absolute path

Comment: It is that simple!!!!! :) Thank you my friend. It works. I just copied the above code as it is and removed the .ttf and VIOLA!!!! This is only thing I did not do with this code. Thanks.